# Javascript : White space string boolean conversion

Tags: javascript

In Javascript :

```
!!" " == true // => true
" " == true // => false

if ("  " == true){a = 1;} else {a = 0;}
a; // => 0

if ("  "){b = 1;} else {b = 0;}
b; // => 1
```

Any idea about what goes on here?

Comment: Are you asking about falsey values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's step through your examples:

```
!!" " == true // => true
```

You've converted the string " " to a boolean by negating it.  A string with nonzero length will evaluate to true when converted to a boolean, so negating it twice results in the boolean value of true.  `true == true` obviously.  This example does not result in the second parameter being converted to a string because the unary `!` operator has higher precedence than the `==` operator, so by the time the `==` operator is evaluated, both operands are the same type (boolean).

```
" " == true // => false
```

Per Mozilla docs (relevant section shown in [patrick dw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216362/javascript-white-space-string-boolean-conversion/4216618#4216618)), both operands are converted to a number if either operand is a number or a boolean.  You end up with `0 == 1`, which is false.

<strike>In this case, I believe the *second* parameter is being coerced into a string.  You're essentially doing `" " == "true"`, which is false.  This is a comparison of strings, not a comparison of string and boolean.</strike>

```
if ("  " == true){a = 1;} else {a = 0;}
```

This is the same as the previous one:  one operand is a boolean, so both values are converted to a number.

```
if ("  "){b = 1;} else {b = 0;}
```

This is the same as the first one.  The string is coerced into a boolean value.  The string has a nonzero length, so it returns true.

Comment: Oooh ok : "Per Mozilla docs, both operands are converted to a number if either operand is a number or a boolean." That explains everything. Thanks !

Comment: Jonathon - Just a friendly note for future reference. If you're going to borrow information from another answer (if indeed it came from mine) or from any other source really, it is a good idea to give acknowledgement of the fact in your answer. ;o)

Comment: @patrick dw -- apologies, I try to be conscientious about that.  I had been glancing at the Mozilla docs and your answer did tip me off to the section that I needed to read closer.

Comment: Jonathon - Thanks. Your answer gave a nice explanation. +1 :o)

Answer (score 4):

From section **9.3.1** in ECMAScript 5, with regard to converting strings to numbers:

> A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0.

And [from MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string if possible.

So since the string is being compared to a boolean, an attempt is made to convert it to a number. And since an empty string or a string with only white space is converted to `0`, then it would be considered false.

```
" " == false; // true
" " == 0;     // true
"false" == false;   // false because  "false" can't be converted to a number
```

So when you do:

```
!!" "
```

You're no longer relying on the `==` to do conversions for you. Instead you're converting it manually using your own criteria, which is to not convert it to a number, but rather to convert it to a boolean before the `==` takes place.

So you're doing `true == true` or probably actually `1 == 1`.

To see the string with only white space converted into a number, use the unary `+` operator like this:

```
alert( +"  " );  // alerts 0
```

Comment: Woops, adjusted my answer.  Had the string compared to boolean wrong.

Answer (score 0):

String of length equal a value of true.
String evaluation to Boolean is false since they're not the same datatype.

The double `!!` is a not-false operation usage.

So you're saying:

" " == false -> false == false -> true == true

Breakdown:

```
(!(!" ") == true)
(!(false) == true)
(true == true)
(true)
```