# string to boolean conversion behaviour

Tags: javascript

***Are all non empty strings evaluated to true?***

From [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf):

> ```
> Table 11 - ToBoolean Conversions
>
> Undefined: false
> Null: false
> Boolean: The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
> Number: The result is false if the argument is +0, -0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.
> String: The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.
> Object: true
> ```

the answer should be yes. But then i'm wondering why:

```
alert(" " == false);
```

returns **true**. {same result with e.g `"\t\n\r"`}

I don't have any particular use case, I'm just wondering it.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376179/n-t-r-0-is-true/10377034. `false` is converted to `0`.

Comment: @FelixKling thx, i've searched, couldn't find it.

Comment: Ok, i voted to close question because of duplicate... ;) Will accept first answer. Thx to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because JavaScript describes whitespace only strings as having a *toNumber* conversion to `0`.

You can test this using the unary `+` operator:

```
console.log(+"\t\n\r"); // 0
```

Because the `==` isn't so simple as a *toBoolean* conversion, you don't get the same result as you would if you did `!!"\t\n\r"`, where the *toBoolean* conversion considers all non-empty strings to be `true`.

When the `==` is used with operands of different types, the algorithm *usually* coerces the types down until they're both numbers. That's why the *toNumber* conversion is relevant here.

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yes, that's an example of a whitespace-only string. Those are escape sequences that are just part of the literal syntax. The resulting string will only have whitespace. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0.

See page 44 in the PDF you linked

Comment: Damn, thx! Page 44, noted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216362/javascript-white-space-string-boolean-conversion for a more detailed answer

Comment: I can only accept one answer but guess you know that :(

Comment: And ya, i stopped page 43, shame on me